# TextureRegion split doesn't work

Tags: java, android, libgdx

When I try to split a texture it doens't work, when I draw it in screen it draw the same 4 textures that are the same that original Texture. I use the following code to split a texture.

```
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("fondo1.png"));
TextureRegion[][] regs = TextureRegion.split(texture, texture.getWidth() / 2, texture.getHeight() / 2);
Random rand = new Random();
        int x,y;
        for (int i=0; i < regs.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < regs[i].length; j++){
                x = rand.nextInt(500);
                y = rand.nextInt(500);
                parts.add(new ImageActor(regs[i][j].getTexture(),x,y, regs[i][j].getRegionWidth(), regs[i][j].getRegionHeight()));
            }
        }
```

The textures then are loaded in an Actor subclass and draw via stage.

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is in the first argument of the `ImageActor` constructor. You are sending the full texture by calling `regs[i][j].getTexture()`.

The `getTexture()` method of a `TextureRegion` returns the full texture that the Region references.

You should send it the `TextureRegion regs[i][j]`, and modify your `ImageActor` so it can receive and draw a `TextureRegion`.